# Java test two binary trees are the same

Tags: java, binary-tree

Update:
The best solution should be:

```
public boolean isSameTree(TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {

    if(p==null&&q==null) return true;
    if(p==null||q==null) return false;

    return isSameTree(p.left, q.left)&&isSameTree(p.right, q.right)&&(p.val==q.val);
}
```

---

Update:
Thank you all, I know those other solutions you told me, but my question is that why my solution doesn't work. Is it because that I ignore some return values? Thank you!

---

I have written a code for determining whether two binary trees are the same, I used recursive method to search through the tree, but this code sometimes didn't work, could you please help me to figure it out?

Thanks a lot!
Here's the code:

```
/*Definition for a binary tree node.
  public class TreeNode {
  int val;
  TreeNode left;
  TreeNode right;
  TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
*/

public boolean isSameTree(TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
    if(p!=null){
        if(q!=null&&p.val==q.val){
            isSameTree(p.left, q.left);
            isSameTree(p.right, q.right);
        }
        else return false;
    }else{
        if(q!=null) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Input:
[10,5,15]
[10,5,null,null,15]
Output:
true
Expected:
false

Comment: If your current output does not match your desired output, and you don't know why, then it's time to start debugging. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please have a look at: [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: isSameTree() has a return value. Do not ignore it.

Comment: @duffymo it's safe to use == for int

Comment: Sure, but those are TreeNode instances, not ints.

Comment: @duffymo When comparing x.val where x is a TreeNode, the int value val is accessed and == is valid for comparing with another int.  For the cases where val is not accessed, TreeNodes variables will be compared.  However, since they are comparing the p and q variables to null, they are checking whether the variables have null references.  If they were to try comparing p == q for object equality (equal values within the objects), then it would be wrong.  That's not the case in their answer and mine, so our answers are valid.  Think about the variables as pointers if you have C experience.

Comment: Not a very efficient way but works. Try doing pre/in/post order traversal for both the trees and store the values in an array. Compare the array.

Comment: @NewUser why would traversing and storing in an array be more efficient?  At what point would you compare the arrays?  Just after the whole traversal?  Are there traversal methods with which I'm not aware?  Edit: maybe the comparisons are inefficient along the way?

Comment: @MattGoodrich: Yes, as I mentioned in my previous comment my solution is not efficient. Having said that, the arrays can be compared after one tree traversal is completed. Which will add a cost of O(N) - if size of first tree is N. That's why it is inefficient.

Comment: @NewUser oh I misread your comment, sorry!

Comment: @Changming Sun  Thanks! But why I can't ignore the return value?

Answer (score 0):

You are just calling isSameTree for the child trees, but not checking their return values.  Concise and correct version:

```
public boolean isSameTree(TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
   if (p == q) { //Will accept null == null
      return true;
   }
   return p != null && q != null && p.val == q.val && 
      isSameTree(p.left, q.left) && isSameTree(p.right, q.right);
}
```

Also, @duffymo was incorrect stating you needed to use .equals() instead of ==.  You are comparing the val's, which are primitives.

Comment: p == q check is not a valid check as this is the actual question we are trying to solve

Comment: If they both reference the same object, then they will be logically equivalent.  They did not specify if they would like a guaranteed deep-comparison.  Thus, I chose the more efficient solution.

Comment: This has nothing to do with how do we search. "if they reference the same  object". Well! Isn't that we are trying to solve? isn't this the actual problem?If  we know p == q or not then there nothing  eft to solve. All other if statements are redundant then

Comment: Please explain how they can reference the same object (or null in the case of my code) and not be equal.

Comment: They will reference the same object when both node have same data and there left and right nodes of both nodes carry the same data. The null case is implicitly already taken care in your code

Comment: I see what you mean.  Yes it will return the correct result without the p == q, but if p == q, then they must have the same inner data.  Including the p == q prevents the rest of the code from running (which is best to avoid if possible), since we already know they are equal.

Comment: now you have removed redundancy but still the first check should be if  both p and q are null then return true. since  the definition of p==q is the actual question thats why the check is invalid.you are using the equality while defining it. That is my whole point. The equality is already solved in return statement

Comment: "p==q is the actual question thats why the check is invalid" no, it's not the actual question.  The actual question is whether or not two TreeNode objects contain the same integer tree.  If we know they reference the same TreeNode object, they cannot be different.  If you think this is false (which it isn't), please prove it with an example.  If as you stated p==q was the actual question (meaning the question is if they reference the same object), then p == q would be the solution.  You mentioned I removed redundancy, but I reformatted the code and did not remove any redundancy.

Comment: The proof is very simple. Remove everything from method except the if statement and have else case as false. Now make two node with same data. To make it simple don't make left and right node and then use your method to see what it returns. it will never return true even though they are equal.

Comment: If you remove the code in the else, then of course it will return false.  The if just checks a special case, but that doesn't mean the else is not important.  It will quickly return true in a special case where they reference the same object, but is still necessary if they are equal, but separate objects.

Comment: what special case it checks? its just a null check in disguise otherwise its not checking any equality. the equality checking is the actual question (p==q ?)  which answered by your return statement not by if statement. if statement never returns true except when its null.

Comment: Again as a proof, do not remove anything from code. Make two same objects and see which instruction returns true. the if statement will never return true(which according to you should return true) which proves that equality check in if is invalid and we should actually do a null check

Comment: It's not just a null check in disguise.  It checks if they reference the same exact object.  I contradicted your argument by writing code to match what you requested and it returned true.  I even implemented the TreeNode class to prevent you from saying it's class specific.  Code and output: https://gist.github.com/mrgoodrich/bc3e3d42cfb9f89e77356e98fbe07ca7

Comment: Also, the if statement is significant in terms of efficiency.  Image the TreeNode has thousands of children.  If we are able to detect the same object is referenced, we may avoid a huge recursive search comparing a tree to itself.

Comment: TreeNode test = new SomeTreeNodeClass();
 TreeNode another = new SomeTreeNodeClass(); let me know what does it return

Comment: I can tell you it will return false.  That does not mean the if statement is not valuable.  I explained why in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public boolean isSameTree(TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
        if(p!=null){
            if(q!=null&&p.val==q.val){
                if(!isSameTree(p.left, q.left)) return false;
                if(!isSameTree(p.right, q.right)) return false;
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }else{
            if(q!=null) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: This solution is incorrect.  At the time of my comment the code: if(!isSameTree(p.left, q.left)) return false; if(!isSameTree(p.right, q.right)) return true; should not return true if the right subtrees are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a get method to retrieve data.One way you can solve  is to let isSameTree methods to accept null values and then compare.

```
public boolean isSameTree(TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {

        if (p == q) {
            return true;
        }
        if (p == null || q == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return p.get().isSameTree(q.get()) &&
               isSameTree(p.left(), q.left()) &&
               isSameTree(p.right(), q.right());
    }
```

Another way is the following:

```
public boolean isSameTree(TreeNode p, TreeNode q) 
    {

        if (p == null && q == null)
            return true;


        if (p != null && q != null) 
            return (p.get == q.get
                    && isSameTree(p.left, q.left)
                    && isSameTree(p.right, q.right));


        return false;
    }
```

Comment: The check p==q is the actual problem that OP is trying to solve

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
public boolean isSameTree(TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
   if (p == null && q == null) 
        return true; 


    if (p != null && q != null)  
        return (p.val == q.val 
                && isSameTree(p.left, q.left) 
                && isSameTree(p.right, q.right)); 


    return false;  
}
}
```